# GCM API on device, but FCM API key on server

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, deprecated

What are the implications to the android app after April 11 2019. If my binary still has GCM broadcast reciever and no FCM. But my server is FCM compatible and uses FCM API Key.

Will the binary crash after april 2019, or not be able to upload on play store ?
Will it be specific to new Android OS launched ?.

Regards
Kushal

Comment: What do you mean by *binary*?

Comment: android mobile application binary. Which will be installed on device.